# How to change list of foreign keys for a formset generated by django inlineformset_factory?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following models:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}"

class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='categories')

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = "category"
       verbose_name_plural = "categories"
       order_with_respect_to = 'organization'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12)
    stock = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='producs', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'organization'
```

I want an inline formset where the user can add products, but I want to show only the categories that are registered to the current user's organization(accessible by `request.user.organization`)

Right now, this is how the formset is set up:

```
def addProducts(request):
   ProductFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Organization, Product, exclude=('organization',), extra=5)
   organization = request.user.organization
   if request.method == "POST":
      formset = ProductFormSet(request.POST, 
        instance=organization, queryset=Product.objects.none())

   else:
      formset = ProductFormSet(
        instance=organization, queryset=Product.objects.none())


   context = {"forms": formset}

   return render(request, "products/product_form.html", context=context)
```

But, as you can probably guess, the select field is showing all categories, not just the one's that have the same organization.
How do I pass `Category.objects.filter(organization=organization)` to the select field?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it:

Wrap the ProductForm in a function:

```
def productform_factory(organization):

class ProductForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["category"].queryset = Category.objects.filter(
            organization=organization)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['brand', 'name', 'code', 'sale_price', 'stock', 'category']


return ProductForm
```

Change the view code to this:

```
organization = request.user.organization
ProductFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Organization, Product, form=productform_factory(organization), extra=4)

if request.method == "POST":
    formset = ProductFormSet(request.POST,
        queryset=Product.objects.none())
else:
    formset = ProductFormSet(
        queryset=Product.objects.none())

context = {
    # 'form': form,
    'title': 'Add Product',
    'formset': formset
}
return render(request, "products/product_form.html", context=context)
```